# How to search no of strings from a no of text files In a given directory

Tags: perl

I want to search my string Input at consol i.e. "VoLTE SIPTX: [SIPTX-SIP] ==>  REGISTER" from the no of files In a directory (Sample data of the file Is shown below) but unable to do the same in the below code.

Here is my code:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Entering the value i.e. the IMS Message to compare with";

my $value       = '';
my $choice      = '';
my $loop        = '';
my $IMS_Message = '';
my $search      = '';
my $kw          = '';

print "\nThe script path & name is $0\n";
print "\nPlease enter desired number to select any of the following   

    (1) Start Comparing REGISTER message !!
    (2) Start Comparing SUBSCRIBE message
    (3) Start Comparing INVITE message \n";

$value = <STDIN>;

if ( $value == 1 ) {

    print "\n Start Comparing REGISTER message\n\n";
    $IMS_Message = "VoLTE SIPTX: [SIPTX-SIP] ==>  REGISTER";
}
elsif ( $value == 2 ) {

    print "\n SUBSCRIBE message Flow\n\n";
}
elsif ( $value == 3 ) {

    print "\n INVITE message Flow\n\n";
}
else {

    print "\nThe input is not valid!\n";
    print "\nDo you want to continue selecting a Automation Mode again (Y or N)?\n";

    $choice = <STDIN>;

    if ( $choice eq /[Yy]/ ) {
        test_loop();
    }
    else {
        exit;
    }

    $kw = $IMS_Message;

    #$search = qr/\Q$kw/;
    $search = quotemeta( $kw );

    for my $file ( grep {-f} glob '*main_log' ) {

        open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};

        while ( <$fh> ) {

            if ( /$search/ ) {

                printf "Found keyword %s in file %s, line %d: %s\n", $kw, $file, $., $_;
                last;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is data of my files from which I want to search my string

```
**TempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTemp
*TempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTemp
VoLTE SIPTX: [SIPTX-SIP] ==> REGISTERTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTemp
tempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTemp
temptempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTemp
***tempTeTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTemp
```

the below code with command line does not work

```
use strict;
use warnings;


    my $value = '';
    my $choice = '';
    my $loop = '';
    my $IMS_Message = '';

    print "\nThe script path & name is $0\n";
    print "\nPlease enter desired number to select any of the following   


    (1) Start Comparing REGISTER message !! !!

    (2) Start Comparing SUBSCRIBE message

        (3) Start Comparing INVITE message \n";;

    $value = <STDIN>;

    if ($value == 1 )
    {

        print "\n Start Comparing REGISTER message\n\n";
        my $IMS_Message = 'VoLTE SIPTX: [SIPTX-SIP] ==>  REGISTER';
        &IMS_Message_Check;
    }

    elsif ($value == 2)
    {

        print "\n SUBSCRIBE message Flow\n\n";

    }
    elsif ($value == 3)
    {

    print "\n INVITE message Flow\n\n";

    }
    else 
    {
        print "\nThe input is not valid!\n";
        print "\nDo you want to continue selecting a Automation Mode again (Y or N)?\n";

        $choice = <STDIN>;
        if( $choice =~ /[Yy]/) {        
            test_loop();
        } else {
            exit;
        }
    }


sub IMS_Message_Check{

print "\n";
print "Start Comparing REGISTER message\n\n";

#my $IMS_Message = 'VoLTE SIPTX: [SIPTX-SIP] ==>  REGISTER';


my $kw = $IMS_Message;
my $search = qr/\Q$kw/;
for my $file ( grep { -f } glob '*main_log' ) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};
    while ( <$fh> ) {
        if ( /$search/ ) {
            printf "Found keyword %s in file %s, line %d: %s\n", $kw, $file, $., $_;
            #last;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are the asterisks `*` part of the data?

Comment: I didn't intend you to just copy your old question and publish it again -- you said that, even with my fix in place, your code output nothing. Please show the code including what you have done with my fix, or we shall never progress.

Comment: I also asked to please tidy your code so that it is more readable. Never mind, just post what you have and I will do it for you.

Comment: @Borodin is feeling generous today. :)

Comment: @simbabque: Any way to get the idea across works for me :) The principle of *six degrees of separation* says that I am almost certain to have this code on my desk tomorrow! I think rocky has vanished for the day anyway.

Comment: Complete aside: wouldn't software engineering benefit from the apprentice pattern? That way, junk like this should never appear in the first place, and if it did there would be a *needs to be apprenticed* close reason!

Comment: @rocky: Please, are the asterisks `*` part of the data?

Comment: @Borodin you seem very bored today. Maybe you should sign up for the [pull request challenge](http://cpan-prc.org/). :)

Comment: @rocky: I'm actually damn busy. Maybe I'm in denial

Comment: asterisks are part of this data but actual string does not have asterisks.I have enabled $search = quotemeta( $kw ); but I did not get the output.

Comment: I have already pasted the full code I am using to output with Data as input In my above code.

Comment: I have already taken your suggestions Into above code :)

Comment: @Borodin in Germany you can do an apprenticeship to become _Fachinformatiker/Anwendungsentwicklung_ (which is translated to _IT specialist/software development_ in my official papers). It's a regular three year on the job training and vocational school. I've been training those for the last 5 years, in Perl. But that book sounds good, I'll use it.

Comment: @simbabque: "That book"? If you mean *six degrees of separation* then that was a joke. I'm sorry, I should flag my words as such on an international forum. It was an urban principle before it was a film, and I didn't know that there was a book. Or perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: @Borodin no, I meant _Apprenticeship Patterns_, which seems to come from a book, published by O'Reilly. http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001813/index.html

Comment: @simbabque: If Fachinformatiker has a Perl option then I'm impressed already. Could you write to your MP to ask for it to be made a legal requirement?

Comment: @simbabque: Oh, gosh. I thought I was stretching the concept of programming patterns to cover sociological ideas. It seems that someone beat me to it. Yes, I must read it too!

Comment: @Borodin no it doesn't. It has no programming language requirement. You find a job at a company that will train you and then you end up with the languages they do. In my case that was Perl ten years ago. See where it got me... Anyway, in vocational school they usually use specific languages to teach certain things, like Java for OOP and PHP for web, wor C# and MSSQL because the schools get all the MSDN stuff for free.

Comment: @simbabque: I have had so many people thank me for teaching them OO programming through Perl, it's bizarre. Perl exposes its mechanisms, and to many people it seems far more simple once the theory matches the languages. IMO Java hides too many things for its own good, and once I can spare the time I know I will understand `Moose` better for knowing what it's working with. Dammit, even `Try::Tiny` makes little sense until you realise that `try` is `sub try (&;@)` and effectively just `sub try (&&&)`.

Comment: @simbabque: I will. Thank you. Gotta go. I'd appreciate your comments on my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there are two main problems with your code

- You have added my solution into the ***The input is not valid*** branch of your consecutive `if` statement. That is why I asked you to keep your code tidy and indented properly. You would have spotted it yourself if your indentation was at all organised
- Your program is searching for `VoLTE SIPTX: [SIPTX-SIP] ==>  REGISTER` while the text in the file is `VoLTE SIPTX: [SIPTX-SIP] ==> REGISTER` (your program has two spaces before `REGISTER` while your data has just one). Isn't that an obvious thing to check for?

I feel certain that you could have discovered these things for yourself, and you could certainly have read [*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of posting very poor code and no sample data in the first place

I've ignored your command-line menu (which shouldn't be in the code at this stage anyway) including your call to the non-existent `test_loop`, and have written this, which performs properly. The bulk of it is a copy of the solution I provided to your previous question, which you said wasn't working

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "\n";
print "Start Comparing REGISTER message\n\n";

my $IMS_Message = 'VoLTE SIPTX: [SIPTX-SIP] ==> REGISTER';

my $kw = $IMS_Message;

my $search = qr/\Q$kw/;

for my $file ( grep { -f } glob '*main_log' ) {

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};

    while ( <$fh> ) {

        if ( /$search/ ) {

            printf "Found keyword %s in file %s, line %d: %s\n", $kw, $file, $., $_;
            last;
        }
    }
}
```

#### output

```
Start Comparing REGISTER message

Found keyword VoLTE SIPTX: [SIPTX-SIP] ==> REGISTER in file xmain_log, line 3: VoLTE SIPTX: [SIPTX-SIP] ==> REGISTERTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTempTemp
```

Comment: ..I noticed that the above code worked without command line menu but does not with command line menu. I have pasted the code with command line menu.

Comment: @rocky: No. Go away and learn Perl properly. Even now you can't be bothered to lay out your code reasonably, you have ignored my advice to remove `&` from subroutine calls, and you haven't tried to examine the values of variables using diagnostic `print` calls. The problem is that you're ***careless*** and you ***don't know Perl***, and Stack Exchange isn't the place to learn it. After two or three years of studying, if you still get stuck, then you should at least understand the answers you are given here.

Comment: @rocky: The main problem is that you have commented out my line `#my $IMS_Message = 'VoLTE SIPTX: [SIPTX-SIP] ==>  REGISTER'`.